# Getting Error Log when phone is disconnected from PC

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, logging, windows-phone-7.1

I have a WP7 app for the mango version. When I deploy the app to the phone through the Application Deployment tool I can't get the error logs or the log report. I needs logs to check what is happening behind. Its important. How can I achieve this? Is there  a way to get record and get the log of the app that is running? Am using logger statements as below:

```
#if LOG_ENABLED
                                Logger.log(TAG, "Client not received any UserId from server response.. so Exiting the application.");
#endif
```

and the logger class is implemented like this:

```
 public static void log(string tag, string str)
    {
#if LOG_ENABLED
        string  strMsg= new StringBuilder().Append(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()).Append(" , ").Append(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()).Append(" : ").Append(tag).Append(" : ").Append(str).ToString();            
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Telus Application log : "+strMsg);           
       // LogOffline(strMsg);
#endif
    }

 internal static void log(Exception e)
    {
#if LOG_ENABLED
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Telus Application log : {0}", e.StackTrace);
#endif
    }
```

I have no problem to get the logs when the emulator is running or even if the app is deployed on the phone through Visual Studio.

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Solution would be to write the Log into the IsolatedStorage. You can then access the IsolatedStorage either by using the IsolatedStorageTool or you can add an Option into your App which shows it in-App.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` only outputs the message in the Visual Studio Output window when *debugging* an app (and of course Visual Studio needs to be connected to the Windows Phone emulator or device).

Comment: I am getting the log and thats no problem. I want to get the logs when the Device (Phone) is not connected to VS.

Comment: In that case, you should write the log in the isolated storage like @GnrlKnowledge said.  Here is how to read and write text in the isolated storage : http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files.  Another solution would be to use the LittleWatson class. It will help you reporting exceptions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx